# How do I show that this expression vanishes when it approaches infinity?

Tags: complex-numbers

> The impedance $Z$ is related to the capacitance $C$ and the resistance $R$ via $Z = (R^{-1} + iwC)^{-1}$, where $w$ is the frequency applied. Show that the impedance can be in the form of $Z = Z' - iZ''$ and then show that $Z''$ and $Z'$ vanishes in the high-frequency limit.

First I found out what is $Z'$ and $Z''$

$Z' = \frac{R^{-1}}{R^{-2} + w^2 C^2}$

$Z'' =\frac{wc}{R^{-2} + w^2 C^2}$

High frequency limit means $w$ approaches infinity.

that means $Z'$ is going to become a very small number or in other words approaches zero$

but what about $Z''$ ?

$Z'' =\frac{(\infty) c}{R^{-2} + (\infty)^2 C^2}$

How do I show or understand how $Z''$ vanishes?

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule

Comment: Or $\lim_{w\to \infty} \frac{wc}{R^{-2} + w^2 C^2}=\lim_{w\to \infty} \frac{\frac{c}{w}}{\frac{R^{-2}}{w^2} + C^2}=\frac{0}{0+C^2}=0$ (if $C\neq 0$)

Comment: You could also get the limit directly based on $|Z|^2 = \frac{1}{R^{-2}+w^2 C^{-2}} \to 0$, then that implies $Z' \to 0$ and $Z'' \to 0$ because $|z| = 0 \iff z = 0$.